# Getting correct elevation from hgt file

Tags: elevation, srtm, hgt

When reading SRTM3 data from a .hgt file I get the wrong elevation of a specific latitude longitude and I can't see why.
Maybe someone can see the problem ?

My coordinate is near Lissabon in the sea and I expect an elevation around 0 or no elevation data, which means 0 as well. But I get an elevation of 32 meters. Something is slightly shifted, but I cant see what.

My coordinate :
[image]

My code in Java with values at the end of the lines for analysing:

[image]

Can someone see, what I am calculating wrong ?

Java code as text:

```java
public double readElevation(LatLon coor) {
    System.out.println(coor);
    String tag = getHgtFileName(coor);

    ShortBuffer sb = cache.get(tag);

    if (sb == null) {
        return NO_ELEVATION;
    }
    // see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43743/how-to-extract-elevation-from-hgt-file
    double fLat = frac(coor.getLatitude()) * SECONDS_PER_MINUTE;
    double fLon = frac(coor.getLongitude()) * SECONDS_PER_MINUTE;

    // compute offset within HGT file
    int row = (int) Math.round(fLat * SECONDS_PER_MINUTE / HGT_RES);
    if(fLat < 0){
        row = row * -1;
    }else{
        row = HGT_ROW_LENGTH - row;
    }
    int col = (int) Math.round(fLon * SECONDS_PER_MINUTE / HGT_RES);

    int cell = (HGT_ROW_LENGTH * (row - 1)) + col;

    // valid position in buffer?
    if (cell < sb.limit()) {
        short ele = sb.get(cell);
        System.out.println("==> Read SRTM elevation data from row/col/cell " + row + "," + col + ", " + cell + " = " + ele);
        // check for data voids
        if (ele == HGT_VOID) {
            return NO_ELEVATION;
        } else {
            return ele;
        }
    } else {
        return NO_ELEVATION;
    }
}
```

Comment: SRTM in DTED format is column-major from the southwest, not row major from the northeast, so you probably want to double-check your math.

Comment: I am very unsure what this means. Do you think "int cell = (HGT_ROW_LENGTH * (row - 1)) + col;" is wrong, right. I guess row and col are correct but cell is wrong. Do you think too ?

Comment: I'm not going to do Java math in my head before noon, but your cell calculation is [row-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order).  This is the sort of thing that diagnostic print statements and debugging are for.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue in my case.
if I have a negativ longitude I have to read from a previous .hgt.
In my case I read from N38W009.hgt, which is wrong.

I have to read from N38W010.hgt.